# Laravel Eloquent query ignoring column value

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, relationship

On my search method in the `Models\Article::class` I'm able to get all the results, even in the multiple relations with Categories and Tags, but the issue, that I've been trying to solve, unsuccessfully, is that I just want the results for the published articles – my db column for this is a bool 'active'.

I've tried different approaches by switching the `->where('active', 1)` clause around but the results are the same. It brings all the active and non active.

I have in development 8 articles but only 7 with active = 1. When I perform the search, the response sends all the 8, ignoring the `where('active', 1)` clause. Probably I'm missing or messing something here in the following method:

```php
// Method in the Article Model class
public function getSearchResults($query)
{
    return $this->where('active', 1)->where('start_publishing', '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->where('external_reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('byline', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('published_by', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('subhead', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('lead_story', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orWhere('meta_keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->with('categories')->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($query) {
                $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
            })
            ->with('documents')->orWhereHas('documents', function ($q) use ($query) {
                $q->where('doc_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
                //$q->where('doc_description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%');
            })
            ->with('tags')->orWhereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($query) {
                $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
            })
            ->with('images')
            ->orderBy('type', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(15);
}
```

Thanks in advance fr any help here on this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the suggestion below, I was fooled by the query I was making, since all the results where in a group of `active=1`. Now, performing a different query, where there is one article with `active=0` this one still appears in the results. In summary, still with the same problem of getting only Active articles..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after Davit's suggestion, which at the beginning seemed like to work, but it was the query I was doing that was "faking" the results, I finally managed to make it work.

Taking the code David suggested, I made a few changes, through the logic of how the query gets constructed and ended up with a final working method that will return only the active Articles matching the "query" criteria from the request. Below the final method code:

```php
// Method in the Article Model class
public function getSearchResults($query)
{
    return $this->where('active', 1)
            ->where('start_publishing', '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
                $q->where('external_reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('byline', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('published_by', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('subhead', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('lead_story', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('meta_keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
                $q->with('categories')->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
                });
                $q->with('documents')->orWhereHas('documents', function ($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('doc_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
                    //$q->where('doc_description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%');
                });
                $q->with('tags')->orWhereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
                });
            })
            ->with('categories')
            ->with('tags')
            ->with('images')
            ->distinct()
            ->orderBy('type', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Result is because you are use orWhere Criteria. For fix it use this

```php
$this->where('active', 1)
     ->where('start_publishing', '<=', Carbon::now())
     ->where(function($q) use ($query) {
         $q->where('external_reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') // the $q here is required
         ->orWhere('byline', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
         ->orWhere('published_by', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
         ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
         ->orWhere('subhead', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
         ->orWhere('lead_story', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
         ->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
         ->orWhere('meta_keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })
    ->with('categories')->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })
    ->with('documents')->orWhereHas('documents', function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('doc_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        //$q->where('doc_description', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%');
    })
    ->with('tags')->orWhereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })
    ->with('images')
    ->orderBy('type', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Hi, yes, and now it even doesn't work. It's throwing exception `"Class App\Models\Article does not exist"`

Comment: fix this `;` in `->orWhere('meta_keywords', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');`

Comment: I've made an edit to your answer because it had a bug. Now, using your suggestion and the bug fixed, it works as expected. Thank you @davit !